# Match the unspecified height of an img with another adjacent div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, flexbox, jsx

This is the JSX of the component in question:

```
import React from 'react'
import * as classes from './PhotoCard.module.scss'

const PhotoCard = ({ img, name, username, profileImg, style }) => 
  <div className={classes.PhotoCardWrapper} style={style}>
    <div className={classes.ImgWrapper}>
      {img}
    </div>
    <div className={classes.Sidebar}>
      <div className={classes.Creator}>
        <div className={classes.ProfilePicture}>
          {profileImg}
        </div>
        <div className={classes.ProfileInfo}>
          <h5>{name}</h5>
          <p>{username}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.Comments}>
        <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Write a comment" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

export default PhotoCard
```

Here is the relevant SCSS:

```
.PhotoCardWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

  .ImgWrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;

    img {
      width: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 5px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    }
  }

  .Sidebar {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;

    .Creator {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      padding: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
      overflow-x: auto;
      box-sizing: border-box;

      .ProfilePicture {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 40px;
        background-image: url('../../static/defaults/placeholder.png');
        background-size: contain;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right: 10px;
        flex-shrink: 0;

        img {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          border-radius: 40px;
        }
      }

      .ProfileInfo {
        height: 40px;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      h5 {
        font-weight: 500;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
      }

      p {
        font-size: 0.7em;
        color: $color-2;
      }
    }

    .Comments {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
      flex-grow: 1;
      background: #525252;

      input {
        border: none;
        border-top: 1px solid $color-1;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        padding: 5px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To explain, I'm trying to preserve the aspect ratio of the image on the left side of the component. I can use an absolute unit for the width however I cannot use an absolute height unit as the height of the component will be based upon the aspect ratio of the image.

The "Sidebar" using flexbox will therefore have to match the height of whatever the unspecified height of the image ends up being. I cannot figure out a solution for this. As you can see I'm trying to use `flex-grow` on the Comments div which will not work without specifying height in parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found to this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import * as classes from './_PhotoCard.module.scss'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const PhotoCard = ({ ident, img, name, profileImg }) => {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(null)
  const [imgClicked, setImgClicked] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => setHeight(document.getElementsByClassName('_PhotoCard_ImgWrapper__3S6GQ').item(ident).clientHeight), [ident])

  const creatorJSX = (
    <>
      <div className={classes.ProfilePicture}>
        {profileImg}
      </div>
      <div className={classes.ProfileInfo}>
        <h5>{name}</h5>
      </div>
    </>
  )

  const imgClickedHandler = () => {
    if (imgClicked === null) {
      setImgClicked(classes.imgClicked)
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"
    } else {
      setImgClicked(null)
      document.body.style = "none"
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={`${classes.PhotoCardWrapper} ${imgClicked}`} style={window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)").matches ? { marginBottom: 40 } : { marginBottom: 20 }}>
      <div className={classes.CreatorMobile}>
        {creatorJSX}
      </div>
      <div className={classes.ImgWrapper} onClick={() => imgClickedHandler()}>
        {img}
      </div>
      <div className={classes.Sidebar} style={window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)").matches ? { height: height } : null}>
        <div className={classes.SidebarTop}>
          <div className={classes.Creator}>
            {creatorJSX}
          </div>
          <div className={classes.Comments}/>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Write a comment" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

PhotoCard.propTypes = {
  ident: PropTypes.number,
  img: PropTypes.element,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  profileImg: PropTypes.element,
}

export default PhotoCard
```

This could only be achieved by implementing some JS witchcraft.